# How can I update test results for an existing HTML Extent Report in version 5.0.6

Tags: java, testng, extentreports

I am trying to use an existing Extent HTML Report rather than creating a new HTML Report in my Java project.

Since I am using version 5.0.6, some methods such as the ExtentHtmlReporter have been deprecated.

I have tests that fail due to test environment issues and when I rerun them, they pass.

What I am trying to achieve is to update the failed test results with the new results without losing the tests that succeeded in my original run.

This is my current code:

```
var htmlReport = new ExtentSparkReporter("testReport.html");
var extentReport = new ExtentReports();

extentReport.attachReporter(htmlReport);
```

Can someone kindly assist me with how I can modify this code to use an existing test report? It currently just creates a new report with the same name (Essentially recreating it) with the test results of my last run and losing my old successful tests.